# How to have multiple functions in jQuery ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can create Jquery functions, but what if you want more functions. 
For example say I wanted to have a function for a drop down list AND a button. 
I can only seem to do one function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
         this.hide();
      });
   });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("banner").click(function() {
        this.fadeTo();
      });
   });
</script>
```

Is this right on how to create multiple functions in one document or is there an easier way to create them? 
Can you show me how to create multiple ones instead of one?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do a little better as it's not clear. If you mean that you want to include more that one function in a script block - you can do that. Place them both within the same `$(document).ready` handler. If you mean that you want to select multiple elements, separate your selectors with commas, `#foo, #bar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both functions can go inside the same document ready function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("banner").click(function() 
        $(this).fadeTo();
    });
});
</script>
```

However, the selector `$("banner")` is invalid, if you're targeting a class of banner it should be `$(".banner")`, ID would be `$("#banner")`

Comment: Furthermore, a double quote is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather use single document ready event and then wrap the two methods in it.

You would need to use class selector as element have class `banner` in it.also double quote is missing at the end of this selector
:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").click(function() {
     $(this).hide();
   });
   $(".banner").click(function() {
     $(this).fadeTo();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in the same `$(document).ready` function - you don't need a new document ready for each event listener.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("banner).click(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo();
    });
});
</script>
```

Also your `$("banner")` selector is invalid - take a look at the jQuery Selectors documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

you only require one `$(document).ready(function () {})`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $("banner").click(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine both and change `$("banner)` to `$(".banner")`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(".banner").click(function() 
        $(this).fadeTo();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

concat button & banner click code in `$(document).ready`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("banner").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the code several time it is fairly easy to write a function that hides a certain element. Then you just have to call the function with a parameter(the value of your DOM.

```
   function hideElement(value)
{
    $('' + value +' ').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo();       
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {
        hidedElement(banner);
        hideElement(button);

    });
```